# How to display all the data from array

Tags: php

I'm having problem with displaying the data from array which I get from function

```
    public function izpis_narocil($user)
{
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM nabava WHERE id_uporabnika=?";
    if( !$this->stmt = $this->mysqli->prepare($sql) )
        throw new Exception("MySQL Prepare statement failed: ".$this->mysqli->error);

    $this->stmt->bind_param("i", $user);
    $this->stmt->execute();

    $result = $this->stmt->get_result();

    if( $result->num_rows == 0)
    return "";

    return $result->fetch_assoc();
}
```

here is the code, where function is called from:

```
<?php

session_start();
require_once(dirname(__FILE__)."/simpleusers/su.inc.php");
include($path."/menu.php");

$SimpleUsers = new SimpleUsers();

$userId = $_GET["userId"];
$user = $SimpleUsers->getSingleUser($userId);
if( !$user )
    die("The user could not be found...");

$izpisnarocil = $SimpleUsers -> izpis_narocil($user[userId]);
```

?>

this code continues with html code for content displaying.

I would like to display all the rows in main file, which call function above.

Thx for help...

Comment: From where you are calling this function to display rows?

Comment: I added the code where function is called from.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To display the result in table change your php code this way.

```
<?php
public function izpis_narocil($user)
{
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM nabava WHERE id_uporabnika=?";
    if( !$this->stmt = $this->mysqli->prepare($sql) )
        throw new Exception("MySQL Prepare statement failed: ".$this->mysqli->error);

    $this->stmt->bind_param("i", $user);
    $this->stmt->execute();

    $result = $this->stmt->get_result();

    if( $result->num_rows == 0)
    return "";

    $data = array();
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
            $data[] = $row;
    }

    return $data
}
?>
```

And the file which is calling the  izpis_narocil() is

```
<?php
   $izpisnarocil = $SimpleUsers -> izpis_narocil($user[userId]);

   $data = "<table>";
   foreach($izpisnarocil as $key=>$value) {
            $data .= "<tr><td>".$value['id_nabava']."</td><td>".$value['datum_vnosa']."</td><td>".$value['vrsta']."</td></tr>";
         }
        $data .= "</table>";
        echo $data;
    ?>
```

And add other fields which you want to display.

Comment: I tried this and I get result:
Warning: Illegal string offset 'id_nabava' in /var/www/html/intra_komunalaBrezice/nabava.php on line 52

Comment: Can you post your array here?

Comment: don't I get array from function above in my question and then with call to that function    $izpisnarocil = $SimpleUsers -> izpis_narocil($user[userId]);
sorry I'm quite new to this function calling thing...

Comment: print_r($izpisnarocil); and post the result.

Comment: Array( [id_nabava] => 78 [datum_vnosa] => 2014-01-17 [vrsta] => 1 [narocilo] => AQUAmax - ?ISTILNA NAPRAVA 4 PE - SBR [kolicina] => 1,0 KOS [os] => 0 [analiza] => 0 [analiza_st] => [datum_analize] => 0000-00-00 [povprasevanje] => 0 [datum_povprasevanja] => 0000-00-00 [sm] => [pr_dobavitelj] => ZAGO�EN [id_uporabnika] => 1 [prevzemnik] => [opomba] => Pla?ilo na 24 obrokov !! [datum_rok] => 0000-00-00 [naroceno] => 0 [narocilnica] => [status] => Z [datum_narocila] => 2014-01-20 [datum_preklica] => 0000-00-00 [opomba_narocilo] => [samonabava] => 0 [datum_dobava] => 2014-01-21 [opomba_dobava] => )

Comment: from the result i can see that result retusn only one row from database. I need all rows. Where is the problem?

Comment: I updated my answer

Comment: still error illegal string offset...

Comment: I succeeded to get this working.
I just changed the loop in:
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
            $data [] = $row;
    }

Comment: Oops.I missed it. I updated my answer. Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

Display Grid View

**Code**

```
 $sql = "SELECT column1, column2,column3 FROM myTableName";
    $result = $conn->query($sql);

    if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
        echo "<table><tr><th>column1</th><th>column2</th><th>column3</th></tr>";
        // output data of each row
        while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
            echo "<tr><td>" . $row["column1"]. "</td><td>" . $row["column2"]. " " . $row["column3"]. "</td></tr>";
        }
        echo "</table>";
    } else {
        echo "0 Results";
    }
```

**Result**

```
+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
+ column1 + column2 + column3 +
+++++++++++ +++++++++ +++++++++
+ val1    +    val2 + + val3  +
+++++++++++ +++++++++ +++++++++
```

Answer (score 0):

After getting the result from database please follow

```
<?php
    $izpisnarocil = $SimpleUsers -> izpis_narocil($user[userId]);

    echo '<table>';
    echo '<thead><tr><th>column1</th><th>column2</th><th>column3</th></tr></thead><tbody>'; 
    foreach($izpisnarocil as $row) {
        echo'<tr>'; 
        echo'<td>'. $row['FieldName1']."</td>";
        echo'<td>'. $row['FieldName2'].'</td>';
        echo'<td>'. $row['FieldName3'].'</td>';
        echo'<tr>';

     }
    echo '</tbody>'; 
    echo '</table>'; 
?>
```

I hope this helps you

Note: **Replace FieldName with your Value**